# reverse geocoding - returning only town/city or country

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map which has a marker on it so people can move it around. When they do I'm attempting to reverse geocode the location into a proper address but I only really want the town/city and the country, I don't want the postcode returned

Is it possible to just get the locality without having to use a regex to remove the postcode - which would prob be difficult!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response didn't  only return the address, it also contains the address_components, an array with the specific details of the location, e.g. country, city, street etc. (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON)

fetch the desired components out of this array.

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle, thanks for helping me. I've tried alerting the results but I'm just getting undefined - I'm using alert(results[1].address_components['country']); is that right?

Comment: No, you can't access the adress_components directly by their type, you must iterate over all address_components and fetch the components with the type-array set to  the desired value. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542788/parsing-city-state-from-google-maps-request/6543029#6543029

Answer (score 2):

Reverse GeoCoding returns an address_components array containing few objects.
(You can print this object in console to get the feel.)
Extracting required information from this array is very easy.
Now have a look at the code -

```
function getLatLong(position) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // Reverse Geocoding, Location name from co-ordinates.
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        var components=results[0].address_components;

        for (var component=0;component<(components.length);component++){
            if(components[component].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
                var admin_area=components[component].long_name;
            }
            if(components[component].types[0]=="country"){
                var country=components[component].long_name;
            }

            if(components[component].types[0]=="postal_code"){
                var postal_code=components[component].long_name;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can!

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        if (results[i].types[0] === "locality") {
                            var city = results[i].address_components[0].short_name;
                            var state = results[i].address_components[2].short_name;
                            alert('Serial=' + i+ ' city=' + city+ ' state=' + state)
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
```