# Google Places api City or Zipcode

Tags: google-maps-api-3, knockout.js, google-places-api

I am using google places api with knockout.js, but the issue that I am having is the ability to filter by City, State or ZipCode.

In this code:

```
var options = {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: "us"
    }
};
```

How do you specify that I want 'geocode' and '(cities)'?

So users can type in City Name or Zipcode?

Current code doesn't work for Zipcode!

Also need to format the result to show City, State instead of City, State Country.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.addressAutocomplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        var options = {
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: "us"
            }
        };
        ko.utils.extend(options, allBindings.autocompleteOptions)

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            result = autocomplete.getPlace();
            value(result.formatted_address);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't use multiple types(except `geocode` & `establishment`)
2. the `types`-option applies a filter to the results, not to the input. When you've set the types to `geocode` , and you don't get a result when a user enters a Zip-code, there are no results for that particular input(the API doesn't recognize that the input is a ZIP-code, it takes the input and searches for anything that matches, no matter if it's a postal_code, a street_number or something else)

To apply a custom format you must parse the address_components, see: [Parsing city/state from Google Maps request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542788/parsing-city-state-from-google-maps-request/6543029#6543029)